# How to make same event mean different things for different functions in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt, tkinter-button

I was wondering if it was possible to have the same event(like-R-click/R-mouse-press), mean different things for different functions :

For example : Moving an object on R-mouse press and also having the same event used for changing the shape of an object(by mouse press and drag).

My requirement :
I am using a code which is used for snipping the area within, so basically it is a canvas which is being used as an overlay....

The problem i'm facing is that the overlay/snipping area never matches the image/pdf area. So currently i'm manually changing the canvas coordinates /Set_Geometry coordinates ,so that it matches the image/pdf (completely).
This process takes too long.
So i wanted to automate this process of changing and moving this overly /canvas by mouse.
There are 2 specific operations i want :

1. Being able to stretch the overlay/ canvas to match the image.
2. Move this canvas around in the screen to place it exactly where the image is present.

Both of these operations i wanted to do using same the "b3-move" button.
Here is the code :

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2




class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        root = tk.Tk()
        screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
   
        x = screen_width/2 - dim[0]/2
        y = screen_height/2 - dim[1]/2
        self.setGeometry(x, y, dim[0], dim[1])
        self.setWindowTitle('Snipping')
        self.begin = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.8)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(
        QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor))
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        print('Capture the screen...')
        self.show()
           
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor('black'), 3))
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(128, 128, 255, 128))
        qp.drawRect(QtCore.QRect(self.begin, self.end))
    

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = self.begin
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.close()
        x1 = min(self.begin.x(), self.end.x())
        y1 = min(self.begin.y(), self.end.y())
        x2 = max(self.begin.x(), self.end.x())
        y2 = max(self.begin.y(), self.end.y())

        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        cv2.imshow('Captured Image', img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        global s
        s = str(x1) +","+str(dim[1] - y1)+","+str(x2)+","+str(dim[1]- y2)
        print(s)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget()
    window.show()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Just bind to all 3: mouse click; mouse motion; mouse release. Then you can just code the logic. If there is little motion between mouse press and mouse release, the user tried to click on the shape. If there is a lot of motion, don't change the shape.

Comment: Are you looking for `'<ButtonPress-3>'`; `'<ButtonRelease-3>'` and `'<Motion>'` or `'<B3-Motion>'` ?

Comment: <B3-Motion> specifically. Otherwise i'll have to bind it to arrow/W,A,S,D.

Comment: So you wasnt aware of that *event-sequenze* ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define event pattern in tkinter and they have the form of `<modifier-modifier-type-detail>`.

So what you can do is to combine event modifier such as `Button3` and types as `Motion` with each other, (e.g.) `root.bind('<Button3-Motion>',button3motion)`

An example can be found below:

```
import tkinter as tk

def button3press(event):
    print('right click')

def button3release(event):
    print('right click ended')

def button3motion(event):
    print('mouse move while right click')

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<ButtonPress-3>',button3press)
root.bind('<ButtonRelease-3>',button3release)
root.bind('<B3-Motion>',button3motion)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've edited the question. My requirement is a little different i think. Nonetheless thanks for this answer.

Comment: @dartigan First of all, you shouldn't mix GUI Toolkits. You shouldn't even have another GUI Toolkit in the same thread. You really shouldn't, even if you know what you are doing. The next thing is, your request isn't clear to me. What is missing in the answer? Besides that I have seen you barley accept an answer or even vote on them, you should support the people that invest time to solve your issues.

Comment: Did you try this code? When you send the values for dims ...it opens up a transleucent canvas ,i want t be able to change the size of this and also move it around..

Comment: @dartigan No, I don't use PyQt, but GUI Toolkits communicate with the underlying os and receive messages and those messages are handled by your toolkit, that's one of the reasons you probably use them. Tkinter for instance sends in some cases event messages to the root window instead of letting the child process the message. Even if you would know how these messages get proceed and you work something out that is bullet proof, the next update on your toolkit can break your app. There are much more considerations than one answer or comment could provide. Its basically a bad ides

Comment: @dartigan you could achive something like this in tkinter and you probably can achieve that in PyQt. You should decide which toolkit you want to use. I think your original question was answered and therefore you could accept it. If you have additional questions, please open a new one. If you decide to use tkinter further, you could notify me and I could take a look.

Comment: My requirement is completely different to the solution you've given. What i want is to use the same bind(of button3) but for different functions :- stretch/resize the canvas and also move the canvas on the screen. I am open to any suggestions .I will try converting this code completely to tkinter.

Comment: @dartigan let me know if you are there.